# How to access iOS native API in an Adobe Air iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios4, adobe, air

Adobe Air for mobile does not support native API calls.  For Android there's a hack around it: http://elromdesign.com/blog/2010/10/29/hacking-native-android-with-air-app-to-allow-air-access-unavailable-apis/

Is there a work around for Adobe Air iOS packager or ADT?

Answer (score 2):

In AIR 3, you can write native extensions to access native API calls. This works for iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows, Mac, and TV.